# In Apigee App Services, can you query an array element?

Tags: apigee

Let's say I've got an App Services entity with the following data:

```
...
times: [
    "3/05/2014 18:00:00",
    "3/06/2014 16:00:00",
],
...
```

Using [query operators](http://apigee.com/docs/app-services/content/querying-your-data), is there a way to reference a particular numbered element in the array?

I've tried the following:

```
select * where times.0 > '3/05/2014 18:00:00' //this one returns no data
select * where times[0] > '3/05/2014 18:00:00' //this one fails with a java error
```

It seems that if there's one element in the array, it works fine just with:

```
select * where times > '3/05/2014 18:00:00'
```

...but not if there are more than one (nor if I wanted to check a particular numbered array element).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to query this scenario without a problem using Apigee's Advanced API Services.  I have a total of 5 entities in my `/items` collection, all having the `times` array. These look like:

```
{
  "uuid": "65d39aba-8df4-11e3-8926-f36d6fff0de6",
  "type": "items",
  "name": "testItem5",
  "created": 1391556657115,
  "modified": 1392920493819,
  "description": "This is a test item 5.",
  "id": "0005",
  "metadata": {
    "path": "/items/65d39aba-8df4-11e3-8926-f36d6fff0de6"
  },
  "times": [
    "3/05/2014 18:00:00",
    "3/06/2014 16:00:00"
  ]
}
```

Only 3 of the items have a value > `3/05/2014 18:00:00`.  When I make the below query:

`/items?ql=select%20*%20where%20times%20%3E%20%273/05/2014%2018:00:00%27`

or unescaped

`/items?ql=select * where times > '3/05/2014 18:00:00'`

the 3 items with a value higher than `3/05/2014 18:00:00` return without any problem.

Comment: Yeah, that works -- but what if you wanted to check a specific array element's value? If you wanted to know if the 3rd value was set to "XYZ"?

Comment: Any reason why you need to know what the value of the 3rd element in the array is?  Why not just see if any value in the array is set to "XYZ"?  `select * where times = '3/05/2014 18:00:00'`.  If really needing to cycle through the array, seems like something you'd want to do on the client side.

Comment: Well, in this case, a bunch of app services data was already built with the 0 element being start time, and the 1 element being end time (instead of key:value pairs). The alternative is to re-parse through existing data to fix it.